# Ubuntu does not start after deleting python3

Tags: uninstall, python3

I have Ubuntu 20.04 version. After deleting python3, I had to restart and since then I cannot access anything any more.

After unlocking the disk, all I can see is the logo of my laptop.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 20.04, but have tagged your release as 14.04?   Which is it? or how does 14.04 relate?  (it's an ESM release and off-topic here)   FYI: Ubuntu relies on `python` very heavily, so if you remove it; on next login/restart you'll have lost access to any feature that needed python (which includes package tools like `apt` which allow you to fix it easily... you need to use basic tools without front-end helpers)

Comment: short and painless install anew after saving your data. Never; ever mess up  python2 and python3!

Answer (score 1):

Python3 is an essential part of your system. Removing Python3 is like removing a wheel from your bicycle.

Yes, you have the power to destroy your system. Use that power carefully. With your great power comes great responsibility. That's how Open Source software works.

1. Boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB (installer) into the "Try Ubuntu" environment.
2. Use that environment to back up your data (un-encrypted).
3. Then reinstall Ubuntu.
4. Then restore your data.